# DDEV - create SFTP user

Tags: docker, sftp, ddev

I have created two containers (ddev-website-web and ddev-api-web) via DDEV.

Now I want to access the website container from the api container via SFTP.

How can I create a SFTP user in DDEV for the website container? Is this possible at all?
The containers are already connected via a router.

Answer (score 0):

I think

1. Install sshd using this technique from [ddev-contrib](https://github.com/drud/ddev-contrib/tree/master/recipes/sshd) will work for you, at least will get you started with having an ssh server
2. Add vsftpd by adding to webimage_extra_packages inthe config.ssh.yaml: `webimage_extra_packages: [vsftpd, openssh-server]` to your .ddev/config.yaml

From there, you may have some extra config to do based on https://linuxopsys.com/topics/install-vsftpd-ftp-server-on-debian